# Spanish equivalent of "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree"

Tags: traducción, modismos, inglés, parentesco, refranes

We use this expression in English (sometimes sarcastically) to refer to a father/mother and son/daughter not being different from one another or being identical in their actions, behaviors, etc. Other similar expressions: "a chip off the old block", "like father, like son".

The use of "salir a ..." came to mind:

> La nieta **sale al** abuelo.

but I wonder if this is good enough and if there are better alternatives to express this idea?

Comment: Hi. It is a fixed expression in English: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apple-doesn-t-fall-far-from-the-tree

Comment: This phrase is often taken to suggest that a *negative* quality is inherited.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/325486/112436.  Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @aparente001 It is just as mentioned in my post; if we are talking about a negative quality being inherited, we use the expression "(sometimes sarcastically)".

Comment: For me, sarcasm is a specific type of negativity (which I don't think fits here).

Answer (score 15):

Your option is perfectly valid, simple and perfectly understood.
If you want to go for a fixed expression, you might use:

> De tal palo, tal astilla

or any of its many variations, like

> Cabra por viña, cual la madre tal la hija
>   Cual el cuervo, tal el huevo
>   Cual es el padre, tal es el hijo
>   Cual es la madre, así las hijas salen
>   Cual es la mama, tal es la hija que la mama
>   De padres gatos, hijos michinos
>   De tal árbol, tal ramo
>   De tal parra, tal racimo
>   De tal simiente, tal gente

You can find even more details, variations, translations, etc [**here**](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58480&Lng=0).

Also, [**WordMagic**](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/en-es/the%20apple%20doesn%27t%20fall%20far%20from%20the%20tree.php) suggests:

> En casa de tamborilero todos son danzantes

Comment: No te olvides del típico «De tal palo tal astilla». Es el más común al menos aquí en México.

Answer (score 4):

Además de "de tal palo, tal astilla", que yo considero el más común en español de España, se me ocurre:

> De casta le viene al galgo.

Answer (score 3):

En Colombia:

> ¿De dónde le saldrán las rayas al tigre?

Otra con tono de humor e ironía:

> ¡ya nos imaginamos de donde son esas rayas!

Comment: I am not sure that means the same as the phrase asked about. It sounds more like the English Can the leopard change its spots?

Comment: Excellent phrase @alvalongo. I do think that it does perfectly match the spirit of the "de tal palo tal astilla", plus adding a tweak of humor and playful tone with its rethoric formulation

Comment: "hijo de tigre sale pintado y de chucha rabipelado"  Otra  «colombianada»

Answer (score 1):

¿Que tal la siguiente?

> Hijo de tigre, pintito.

A mi me gusta por la simple curiosidad del error: los tigres tienen rays, no pintas.

Comment: No es tan claro que sea un error. Acepción 5 del DRAE: *m. Col., Cuba, Méx. y Ven. **jaguar**.* Creo que también lo he oído en ese sentido en Ecuador. Sospecho que antiguamente, sobre todo antes de Linneo, se utilizara para felinos grandes en general, quizás con excepción del león.

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente significa “de tal palo, tal astilla”.

Comment: Lo lamento, pasa que soy nuevo pero lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción, ahora menos conocida y utilizada:

> **Manta que cobija a la madre, cobija a la hija.**